# how to index document with multiple words (phrases) and words permutation?

Tags: dictionary, indexing, solr, solrnet

I need to find a solution to index my documents base on a dictionary. This dictionary contains 3 million phrases. 
I have one big challenge and that is:
I need to index document base on this dictionary only with a consideration that words permutation is also accepted.
For example :
I have a phrase in my dictionary as "beautiful big garden" ,but if the document contains "big beautiful garden" it should be index as "beautiful big garden".
I am thinking a lot but I couldn't find a normal solution within solr, except using synonym filter and word permutation such as below:
beautiful big garden => garden big beautiful ,beautiful garden big, big beautiful garden ,...
but this is not possible because my dictionary contains 3 milions of phrases and many of these phrases have more than 5 words so calculation 5! and make synonym filter is not possible.
Is there any one who can help me with a proper idea, I am a beginner in solr, there should be a way for that.

Thanks in advance
Afrooz

Answer (score 0):

Always sort the phrases into alphabetical order, both in the dictionary and when looking up potential matches.  That way you only need to check one permutation.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i change the order of the text in the documents, consider i am giving a document with 500 words which is a story and the engine need to index this document within solr base on that dictionary, Ok we can say the dictionary sorted alphabetical but the order of the words within document is a matter for solr, I can not track where is the location of these dictionary terms within the document and thats the reason i am using solr to find out and index it for me.

Comment: You might use solr to index individual words, then us a plugin to check the words around it against your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is change the default operation in solr to `AND`. You can specify the same in query as well in your request handler.

Use in query:

```
q.op=AND
```

Update in search handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/select_and" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="q.op">AND</str>
```

`Alternate way to solve it:` You can split the input text into tokens by whitespace and then form the query using each term with `AND` operator. For example:

```
input text: beautiful big garden
search query: q=field:beautiful AND field:big AND field:garden
```

Index your data with following FieldType:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: abhishek Thanks, but i don't know these words within my document. I have a document with 500 to 700 words and i want to annotate that document according to the dictionary, so if i use "and" for all the document  words then the engine will not retrieve anything.

Comment: is it the case that you are indexing the document (500 words) but searching by phrase and it is part of phrase.txt file? Can you please elaborate little more on your question.